# Access the browser window object within webpack configuration file

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I have a webpack project, and I use webpack-dev-server to use it. I want to be able to set some settings in the `window.localStorage` that webpack can use when restarting with their `live-reload` options to determine how to start. In `devServer` I want the `open` option to be dynamically changeable by the data that resides in `localStorage`.

Is this somehow possible? The file is called `webpack.config.babel.js` using `babel/register` to be able to use imports at the top level.

Right now, the `console.log(window)` at the beginning of the configuration file returns undefined. How could I access this object?

```
// webpack.config.babel.js using babel/register

import HtmlWebPackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";
import { tabTracker } from "./src/actions/action_helpers";

module.exports = function(env, argv) {
  console.log(window);

  return {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "html-loader",
              options: { minimize: true }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
        }
      ]
    },
    devServer: {
      target: "web",
      open: (() => console.log(window.localStorage))(),
      proxy: {
        ...
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
        filename: "./index.html"
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"
      })
    ]
  };
};
```

```
// package.json

{
  ...,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
  },
  ...
}
```

I have omitted some information from the 'package.json' and 'webpack.config.babel.js' files that doesn't pertain.

Comment: webpack does not run within the browser, even when using webpack-dev-server, so browser globals like `window` are not available.